# Attaching a javascript function to a page in order to make it execute right before the doPostBack is invoked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback, dopostback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to intercept any postback in a page? - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234542/how-to-intercept-any-postback-in-a-page-asp-net)

I need to achieve the following target: I have an Asp.Net web form and I have a javascript function `function myfunc()`. I know that everytime that a control causes the page to post back, it automatically makes a call to the generated `doPostBack()` javascript function.

What I need to do is finding a way to tell the page to make a call to `myfunc()` right before EVERY call to `doPostBack` is performed.

In few words: before the doPostBack script activates, the page must run another javascript function!

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried to call your function in the onsubmit event on the body tag?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post on how to intercept a postback:

[How to intercept any postback in a page? - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234542/how-to-intercept-any-postback-in-a-page-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried using the ScriptManager Class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx

RegisterScript would be a good start...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx

Comment: No, didn0t use it... how should I do this?? There are several methods but I see no attachScript or similar, I need a bit more time to look better...