# How to access __doPostBack Eventtarget value outside page_load in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using `__doPostBack` to send data from JavaScript to code behind page in ASP.NET application.

The JavaScript is as follows,

```
$('.window_month td').on('click', function () {
    var idName = this.id;
    var selectedid = idName.substring(1);
    $('#hidden').val(selectedid);
    __doPostBack(idName, '');
});
```

I am using the variable like this in .cs page,

```
string s = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
```

I want to use this `__EVENTTARGET` value outside of `page_load` and assign it to a global variable in ASP.NET.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you show the .aspx markup and the related javascript. also you can create a javascript that uses the `__doPostBack()` method that references an event in your .cs file as well also `Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` is an object so I would also suspect that you would need to cast that object to a `(string)` if you plan to assign it's contents to a string variable. I would also use a `Session[""] ` variable personally to hold that information or a hidden field.. Can you report on if you can step into that code or not and report back if there is a issue or not ..?

Comment: checkout this post as well and remember `Google is your best friend` use it sometime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234542/how-to-intercept-any-postback-in-a-page-asp-net

Comment: There is no issue in assigning Request["__EVENTTARGET"] value to string variable s. I just want to access this string variable outside of page_load and assign it's value to a global variable.

Comment: then you will need to have a static property or store it in a Session variable because if your are doing postbacks on the page load the public string variable would be overwritten and set to `string.Empty` on every page load.. I would personally initialize a `HttpContext.Current.Session["Target"] = string.Empty` in the `Global.asax` page in the OnSessionStart method and then assign it and from there you can access it application wide.. does that make sense..? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "global variable"? That doesn't have a specific meaning in C#. Do you just mean a class level field?

Comment: @MethodMan. Yes, it makes sense. And it is solved using Session. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you will need to have a `static property` or store it in a `Session variable` because if your are doing postbacks on the page load the `public string variable` would be overwritten and set to `string.Empty` on every page load.. I would personally initialize a `HttpContext.Current.Session["Target"] = string.Empty` in the `Global.asax` page in the `OnSessionStart()` method and then assign it and from there you can access it application wide.. does that make sense..? :)

Answer (score 0):

Used Session and it worked. Thanks all.